# How to debug Remote Event Receiver for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

How to debug Remote Event Receiver for Sharepoint Online? The only article that I can find is this, https://blog.virtosoftware.com/remote-event-receivers-creating-and-debugging-sharepoint-online/ however is there another way to debug a remote event receiver

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to debug your RERs:

1. Remote debugging
2. Local debugging

**Remote debugging** is convenient, but it requires a lot of prerequisites:

- deploy your app in Azure
- remotely attach from Visual Studio to your Azure Web app instance and debug

It takes time and sometimes doesn't work stable.

From the other hand **local debugging** is much faster, allows you to modify code without re-deploying to host, however, requires a few setup steps.

1. Install nodejs and `ngrok` service
2. Starting `ngrok` and creating a RER, which points to your ngrok service, instead of real URL.
3. Testing your RER locally by pressing F5 in Visual Studio

A good reading about local debug approach available [here](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: I'm glad you liked the blog post Sergei!

Answer (score 0):

We currently use this devtunnel tool provided by MS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/get-started?tabs=windows
You can host a tunnel to your project hosted locally
Its similar to Ngrok but free to use